# WPF, C#. Как сделать так, чтобы при поиске происходило автодополнение совпадающих записей?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, search

Задача стоит такая: Реализуйте поиск, при котором происходит автоподополнение совпадающих записей, не скачивая дополнительные пакеты из Nuget.

Автодополнение - как в браузере, я ввожу ключевое слово в поиск, и выходит подсказка, которая показывает наиболее подходящую запись.

Comment: Что значит "автодополнение" ?

Comment: Регулярные выражения?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ исправил вопрос, простите что не уточнил, если и сейчас до конца не поняли, что имею ввиду, напишите я, попробую раскрыть более подробно вопрос. Спасибо)

Comment: @SmorcIRL Нет, не совсем регулярные выражения.

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950770/autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963022/autocomplete-combobox-for-wpf)